# How to protect route endpoints using Passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I am trying to build user authentication into my simple Node.js app using the tutorial here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619

It works great in terms of protecting the application home page so that it can only be accessed after logging in, but I am having a really hard time restricting my REST endpoints to only logged in users. As in using Postman I can still call the end points without any authentication.

In my route I have the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// if the user is authenticated
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  res.json("not authenticated");
}

/*
 * GET carlist.
 */
router.get('/carlist', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('carlist');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

This doesn't seem to work, even if I actually enter correct credentials I am always returned "not authenticated". What I am I missing here?

### EDIT:

Full code here: https://gist.github.com/tudorific/d99bc51cfbd3d9d732a3bb1b93ed7214

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: which passport method are you using ? and show how you setup passport

Comment: I am using basic authentication. For passport setup, did you want to see the code in the app.js file or the file that has the login strategy? @NetaMeta

Comment: everything that relates to passport make a little gist or pastbin

Comment: @NetaMeta how's this: https://gist.github.com/tudorific/d99bc51cfbd3d9d732a3bb1b93ed7214

Comment: where is passport init ?

Comment: Was just editing to update that :)

Comment: Try adding to any route you want autentication done `passport.authenticate('login'),` and tell me what you get

Comment: @NetaMeta instead of having isAuthenticated?

Comment: Instead of isAuthenticate. use their method

Comment: @NetaMeta well passport is not declared in the route so I get a "passport is not defined" error.

Comment: not defined in the route ? just get passport there

Comment: How can I do that? Do I need to send it as a parameter to app.use in app.js?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yanivkalfa/91b156c2b2d0e4d3e0f21a49dc83c43d

Comment: @NetaMeta Now I just get Bad Request (HTTP 400) returned.

Comment: describe what happened before the changes ?

Comment: @NetaMeta before the changes I would get the "not authenticated" response even if I specified the user credentials in basic authorization on Postman. The response comes from my isAuthenticated method in the code above or on gist.

Comment: revert the changes and change https://gist.github.com/tudorific/d99bc51cfbd3d9d732a3bb1b93ed7214#file-cars-js-route-L6 to `if (req.user) {` if this wont work try , `if (req.session.user) {`

Comment: @NetaMeta same result with both of those, always getting "not authenticated" the account does exist because I log in with it, but I cannot use it to call this endpoint sadly

Comment: Try getting rid of serializer/deserialize and simply add the sessions/checks your self

Comment: @NetaMeta I'm not sure what you mean, all of the tutorials I've been reading online seem to have the serialize/deserialize. Could this issue be because i have a cars route and a login route? Do they both need to be in the same route?

Comment: What I've noticed is that if I don't log into the website and try to access localhost/carlist, I get "not authenticated". If I log in and then try to access localhost/carlist, it displays the correct JSON output. So this is correct. But when I try to access localhost/carlist from postman I get "not authenticated" even if I pass the basic authentication credentials. Is this because of the session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. Since I was using a LocalStrategy the IsAuthenticated method was looking for the credentials in the session rather than at the Basic Credentials I was sending with Postman. So I needed to create the following new BasicStrategy:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
var Employer = require('../models/employer');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    Employer.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      //if (!user.validPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }

      if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){ return done(null, false); }

      return done(null, user);
    });

    var isValidPassword = function(employer, password){
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, employer.password);
    }
}));
```

And then use that strategy in my route like this:

```
router.get('/carlist', passport.authenticate('basic',  function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('cars');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

This would use my basic authentication credentials from Postman to connect to the website.

Thanks to Neta Meta's advice in the comments to my OP I was able to arrive to this result and a bit more reading on the Passport documentation to understand the differences between the strategies.